# Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference?

Tags: fortran

I am doing a multiple integral, there is a parameter  `M_D` which I can modify. Both `M_D=2.9d3` or `M_D=3.1d3` works fine, but when I change it into `M_D=3.0d0` it got an error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F831A103E08
#1  0x7F831A102F90
#2  0x7F83198344AF
#3  0x43587C in __mc_vegas_MOD_vegas
#4  0x400EBE in MAIN__ at MAINqq.f90:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It's very unlikely there is a sigularity which out of range while progressing. From the answer to this kind of problem I found, I guess it's not about array dimension that is out of bounds.

This time I didn't make it to  simplify the problem which can demonstrate my question in order to write less amount of  code .  It's unpractical to post all the code here,  so I post the segment which I think is relevant to the error.

```
module my_fxn
   implicit none   
   private
   public ::  fxn_1   
   public :: cos_theta

   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: S=1.690d8
   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: g_s = 0.118d0
   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: M_D = 3.0d3   !!!
   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: m=172d0
   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: Q=2d0 
   real(kind(0d0)), parameter      :: pi=3.14159d0
   real(kind(0d0)), external       :: CT14pdf
   real(kind(0d0)) :: cos_theta
   real(kind(0d0)) :: s12
   integer         :: i
   contains        
      function jacobian( upper, lower) result(jfactor)
         implicit none
         real(kind(0d0)), dimension(1:6) :: upper, lower
         real(kind(0d0))  :: jfactor

         jfactor = 1d0
         do i = 1, 6
            jfactor = jfactor * (upper(i) - lower(i))
         end do
      end function jacobian



      function dot_vec(p,q) result(fourvectordot)
         implicit none
         real(kind(0d0)) :: fourvectordot
         real(kind(0d0)), dimension(0:3) :: p,q

         fourvectordot = p(0) * q(0)
         do i = 1, 3
            fourvectordot = fourvectordot - p(i) * q(i)
         end do
      end function dot_vec



      subroutine commonpart(p3_0, p4_0, eta, k_v,P3_v, p4_v, s13, s14, s23, s24) 
         implicit none
         real(kind(0d0)), intent(in) :: p3_0, p4_0, eta, k_v, p3_v, p4_v 
         real(kind(0d0)), intent(out):: s13, s14, s23, s24
         real(kind(0d0)) :: sin_theta, &
                            cos_eta, sin_eta,   &
                            cos_ksi, sin_ksi
         real(kind(0d0)), dimension(0:3) :: k1, k2, p3, p4, k 


         sin_theta = sqrt(1-cos_theta**2) 
         cos_eta = cos(eta)
         sin_eta = sqrt(1-cos_eta**2)  
         cos_ksi = (k_v**2-p3_v**2-p4_v**2)/(2*p3_v*p4_v)
         sin_ksi = sqrt(1-cos_ksi**2)

         k1 = [sqrt(s12)/2d0,0d0,0d0, sqrt(s12)/2d0]
         k2 = [sqrt(s12)/2d0,0d0,0d0, -sqrt(s12)/2d0]
         p3 = [p3_0, p3_v*(cos_theta*cos_eta*sin_ksi+sin_theta*cos_ksi), &
               p3_v* sin_eta*sin_ksi, p3_v*( cos_theta*cos_ksi-sin_theta*cos_eta*sin_ksi)]
         p4 = [p4_0, p4_v*sin_theta, 0d0, p4_v*cos_theta]
         do i = 1, 3
         k(i)  = 0 - p3(i) - p4(i)
         end do
         k(0) = sqrt(s12) - p3_0-p4_0

         s13 = m**2- 2*dot_vec(k1,p3)
         s14 = m**2- 2*dot_vec(k1,p4)
         s23 = m**2- 2*dot_vec(k2,p3)
         s24 = m**2- 2*dot_vec(k2,p3)

      end subroutine commonpart

      function fxn_1(z, wgt) result(fxn_qq)
         implicit none 
         real(kind(0d0)), dimension(1:6) :: z      
         real(kind(0d0)) :: wgt
         real(kind(0d0)) :: tau_0
         real(kind(0d0)) :: sigma, tau, m_plus, m_minus,  &   ! intermediate var 
                            p3_v, p4_v, k_v, phi
         real(kind(0d0)) :: s13,s14,s23, s24, gm    
         real(kind(0d0)) :: part1_qq,part_qq,fxn_qq       
         real(kind(0d0)) :: p3_0_max, p4_0_max, eta_max, gm_max, x1_max, x2_max, &
                            p3_0_min, p4_0_min, eta_min, gm_min, x1_min, x2_min
         real(kind(0d0)), dimension(1:6) :: upper, lower
         real(kind(0d0)) :: jfactor

         wgt = 0

         gm_max = M_D
         gm_min = 0.1d0
         z(1)= (gm_max-gm_min)*z(1) + gm_min

         tau_0 = (2*m)**2/S

         eta_max = 2*pi
         eta_min = 0
         z(2) = (eta_max-eta_min)*z(2)+eta_min

         x1_max = 1
         x1_min = tau_0
         z(3) = (x1_max-x1_min)*z(3) + x1_min

         x2_max = 1
         x2_min = tau_0/z(3)
         z(4) = (x2_max-x2_min)*z(4)+x2_min

         s12 = z(3)*z(4) * S
         if (sqrt(s12) < (2*m+z(1)))then
            fxn_qq = 0d0 
            return
            else
         end if

         p4_0_max = sqrt(s12)/2 - ((m+z(1))**2-m**2)/(2*sqrt(s12))
         p4_0_min = m
         z(5) = (p4_0_max-p4_0_min)*z(5)+p4_0_min

         p4_v = sqrt(z(5)**2-m**2) 
         sigma = sqrt(s12)-z(5)
         tau = sigma**2 - p4_v**2
         m_plus = m + z(1)
         m_minus = m - z(1)

         p3_0_max = 1/(2*tau)*(sigma*(tau+m_plus*m_minus)+p4_v*sqrt((tau-m_plus**2)*(tau-m_minus**2)))
         p3_0_min = 1/(2*tau)*(sigma*(tau+m_plus*m_minus)-p4_v-sqrt((tau-m_plus**2)*(tau-m_minus**2)))
         z(6) = (p3_0_max-p3_0_min)*z(6)+p3_0_min

         p3_v = sqrt(z(6)**2-m**2)  
         k_v = sqrt((sqrt(s12)-z(5)-z(6))**2-z(1)**2)

         gm = z(1)

         upper = [gm_max, eta_max, x1_max, x2_max, p4_0_max, p3_0_max]
         lower = [gm_min, eta_min, x1_min, x2_min, p4_0_min, p3_0_min]
         jfactor = jacobian(upper, lower)
         call commonpart(z(6),z(5),z(2), k_v,p3_v, p4_v, s13, s14, s23, s24) 

         include "juicy.m"
         part1_qq = 0d0
         do i = 1, 5
            part1_qq = part1_qq+CT14Pdf(i, z(3), Q)*CT14Pdf(-i, z(4), Q)*part_qq 
         end do

         phi = 1/(8*(2*pi)**4) * 1/(2*s12)
         fxn_qq = jfactor * g_s**4/M_D**5*pi*z(1)**2*phi*part1_qq
      end function fxn_1
end module my_fxn
```

---

[`MC_VEGAS`](http://helac-phegas.web.cern.ch/helac-phegas/helac-onia.html)

```
MODULE MC_VEGAS
!*****************************************************************
!  This module is a modification f95 version of VEGA_ALPHA.for
!  by G.P. LEPAGE SEPT 1976/(REV)AUG 1979.
!*****************************************************************
IMPLICIT NONE
SAVE
INTEGER,PARAMETER                         :: MAX_SIZE=20            ! The max dimensions of the integrals
INTEGER,PRIVATE                           :: i_vegas
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(MAX_SIZE),PUBLIC:: XL=(/(0d0,i_vegas=1,MAX_SIZE)/),&
                                             XU=(/(1d0,i_vegas=1,MAX_SIZE)/)
INTEGER,PUBLIC                            :: NCALL=50000,&             ! The number of integrand evaluations per iteration
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
! You can change NCALL to change the precision
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                                             ITMX=5,&                 ! The maximum number of iterations
                                             NPRN=5,&                 ! printed or not
                                             NDEV=6,&                 ! device number for output
                                             IT=0,&                   ! number of iterations completed
                                             NDO=1,&                  ! number of subdivisions on an axis
                                             NDMX=50,&                ! determines the maximum number of increments along each axis
                                             MDS=1                    ! =0 use importance sampling only
                                                                      ! =\0 use importance sampling and stratified sampling
                                                                      ! increments are concentrated either wehre the
                                                                      ! integrand is largest in magnitude (MDS=1), or
                                                                      ! where the contribution to the error is largest(MDS=-1)
INTEGER,PUBLIC                            :: IINIP
REAL(KIND(1d0)),PUBLIC                    :: ACC=-1d0                 ! Algorithm stops when the relative accuracy,
                                                                      ! |SD/AVGI|, is less than ACC; accuracy is not
                                                                      ! cheched when ACC<0
REAL(KIND(1d0)),PUBLIC                    :: MC_SI=0d0,&              ! sum(AVGI_i/SD_i^2,i=1,IT)
                                             SWGT=0d0,&               ! sum(1/SD_i^2,i=1,IT)
                                             SCHI=0d0,&               ! sum(AVGI_i^2/SD_i^2,i=1,IT)
                                             ALPH=1.5d0               ! controls the rate which the grid is modified from
                                                                      ! iteration to iteration; decreasing ALPH slows
                                                                      ! modification of the grid
                                                                      ! (ALPH=0 implies no modification)
REAL(KIND(1d0)),PUBLIC                    :: DSEED=1234567d0    ! seed of 
! location of the I-th division on the J-th axi, normalized to lie between 0 and 1.
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(50,MAX_SIZE),PUBLIC::XI=1d0
REAL(KIND(1d0)),PUBLIC                    :: CALLS,TI,TSI

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE RANDA(NR,R)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)                        :: NR
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(NR),INTENT(OUT) :: R
INTEGER                                   :: I
! D2P31M=(2**31) - 1 D2P31 =(2**31)(OR AN ADJUSTED VALUE)
REAL(KIND(1d0))::D2P31M=2147483647.d0,D2P31=2147483711.d0
!FIRST EXECUTABLE STATEMENT
DO I=1,NR
   DSEED = DMOD(16807.d0*DSEED,D2P31M)
   R(I) = DSEED / D2P31
ENDDO
END SUBROUTINE RANDA

SUBROUTINE VEGAS(NDIM,FXN,AVGI,SD,CHI2A,INIT)
!***************************************************************
!     SUBROUTINE PERFORMS NDIM-DIMENSIONAL MONTE CARLO INTEG'N
!     - BY G.P. LEPAGE    SEPT 1976/(REV)AUG 1979
!     - ALGORITHM DESCRIBED IN J COMP PHYS 27,192(1978)
!***************************************************************
! Without INIT or INIT=0, CALL VEGAS
! INIT=1  CALL VEGAS1
! INIT=2  CALL VEGAS2
! INIT=3  CALL VEGAS3
!***************************************************************
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,INTENT(IN)                    :: NDIM
REAL(KIND(1d0)),EXTERNAL              :: FXN
INTEGER,INTENT(IN),OPTIONAL           :: INIT
REAL(KIND(1d0)),INTENT(INOUT)         :: AVGI,SD,CHI2A
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(50,MAX_SIZE):: D,DI
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(50)         :: XIN,R
REAL(KIND(1d0)),DIMENSION(MAX_SIZE)   :: DX,X,DT,RAND
INTEGER,DIMENSION(MAX_SIZE)           :: IA,KG
INTEGER                               :: initflag
REAL(KIND(1d0)),PARAMETER             :: ONE=1.d0
INTEGER                               :: I, J, K, NPG, NG, ND, NDM, LABEL = 0
REAL(KIND(1d0))                       :: DXG, DV2G, XND, XJAC, RC, XN, DR, XO, TI2, WGT, FB, F2B, F, F2
!***************************
!SAVE AVGI,SD,CHI2A
!SQRT(A)=DSQRT(A)
!ALOG(A)=DLOG(A)
!ABS(A)=DABS(A)
!***************************
IF(PRESENT(INIT))THEN
   initflag=INIT
ELSE
   initflag=0
ENDIF
! INIT=0  - INITIALIZES CUMULATIVE VARIABLES AND GRID
ini0:IF(initflag.LT.1) THEN
   NDO=1
   DO  J=1,NDIM
       XI(1,J)=ONE
   ENDDO
ENDIF ini0
!  INIT=1    - INITIALIZES CUMULATIVE VARIABLES, BUT NOT GRID     
ini1:IF(initflag.LT.2) THEN
  IT=0
  MC_SI=0.d0
  SWGT=MC_SI
  SCHI=MC_SI
ENDIF ini1
!  INIT=2   - NO INITIALIZATION
ini2:IF(initflag.LE.2)THEN
   ND=NDMX
   NG=1
   IF(MDS.NE.0) THEN
     NG=(NCALL/2.d0)**(1.d0/NDIM)
     MDS=1
     IF((2*NG-NDMX).GE.0) THEN
       MDS=-1
       NPG=NG/NDMX+1
       ND=NG/NPG
       NG=NPG*ND
       ENDIF
   ENDIF
   K=NG**NDIM                      ! K sub volumes
   NPG=NCALL/K                     ! The number of random numbers in per sub volumes Ms
   IF(NPG.LT.2) NPG=2
   CALLS=DBLE(NPG*K)               ! The total number of random numbers M
   DXG=ONE/NG
   DV2G=(CALLS*DXG**NDIM)**2/NPG/NPG/(NPG-ONE)  ! 1/(Ms-1)
   XND=ND                          ! ~NDMX! 
                                   ! determines the number of increments along each axis
   NDM=ND-1                        ! ~NDMX-1
   DXG=DXG*XND                     ! determines the number of increments along each axis per sub-v
   XJAC=ONE/CALLS
   DO J=1,NDIM
      DX(J)=XU(J)-XL(J)
      XJAC=XJAC*DX(J)              ! XJAC=Volume/M
   ENDDO
!     REBIN, PRESERVING BIN DENSITY
   IF(ND.NE.NDO) THEN
      RC=NDO/XND                   ! XND=ND
      outer:DO J=1, NDIM           ! Set the new division
          K=0
          XN=0.d0
          DR=XN
          I=K
          LABEL=0
          inner5:DO
          IF(LABEL.EQ.0) THEN
                  inner4:DO
                    K=K+1
                    DR=DR+ONE
                    XO=XN
                    XN=XI(K,J)
                    IF(RC.LE.DR) EXIT
               ENDDO inner4
          ENDIF
             I=I+1
             DR=DR-RC
             XIN(I)=XN-(XN-XO)*DR
             IF(I.GE.NDM) THEN
                     EXIT
             ELSEIF(RC.LE.DR) THEN
                     LABEL=1
             ELSE
                     LABEL=0
             ENDIF
             ENDDO inner5
           inner:DO I=1,NDM
             XI(I,J)=XIN(I)
           ENDDO inner
           XI(ND,J)=ONE
      ENDDO outer
      NDO=ND
   ENDIF

   IF(NPRN.GE.0) WRITE(NDEV,200) NDIM,CALLS,IT,ITMX,ACC,NPRN,&
                         ALPH,MDS,ND,(XL(J),XU(J),J=1,NDIM)
ENDIF ini2
!ENTRY VEGAS3(NDIM,FXN,AVGI,SD,CHI2A)     INIT=3   - MAIN INTEGRATION LOOP
mainloop:DO
    IT=IT+1
    TI=0.d0
    TSI=TI
    DO J=1,NDIM
       KG(J)=1
       DO I=1,ND
          D(I,J)=TI
          DI(I,J)=TI
       ENDDO
       ENDDO

    LABEL=0
    level1:DO
    level2:DO
    ifla:IF(LABEL.EQ.0)THEN
           FB=0.d0
           F2B=FB
           level3:DO K=1,NPG
              CALL RANDA(NDIM,RAND)
              WGT=XJAC
              DO J=1,NDIM
                 XN=(KG(J)-RAND(J))*DXG+ONE
                 IA(J)=XN
                 IF(IA(J).LE.1) THEN
                    XO=XI(IA(J),J)
                    RC=(XN-IA(J))*XO
                 ELSE
                    XO=XI(IA(J),J)-XI(IA(J)-1,J)
                    RC=XI(IA(J)-1,J)+(XN-IA(J))*XO
            ENDIF
                 X(J)=XL(J)+RC*DX(J)
                 WGT=WGT*XO*XND
              ENDDO

              F=WGT
              F=F*FXN(X,WGT)
              F2=F*F
              FB=FB+F
              F2B=F2B+F2
              DO J=1,NDIM
                 DI(IA(J),J)=DI(IA(J),J)+F
                 IF(MDS.GE.0) D(IA(J),J)=D(IA(J),J)+F2
              ENDDO
           ENDDO level3
!          K=K-1                    !K=NPG

           F2B=DSQRT(F2B*DBLE(NPG))
           F2B=(F2B-FB)*(F2B+FB)
           TI=TI+FB
           TSI=TSI+F2B
           IF(MDS.LT.0) THEN
              DO J=1,NDIM
                D(IA(J),J)=D(IA(J),J)+F2B
              ENDDO
      ENDIF 
           K=NDIM
        ENDIF ifla
        KG(K)=MOD(KG(K),NG)+1
        IF(KG(K).EQ.1) THEN
                EXIT
        ELSE
                LABEL=0
        ENDIF
        ENDDO level2
      K=K-1
      IF(K.GT.0) THEN
              LABEL=1
      ELSE
              EXIT
      ENDIF
      ENDDO level1

!    COMPUTE FINAL RESULTS FOR THIS ITERATION
    TSI=TSI*DV2G
    TI2=TI*TI
    WGT=ONE/TSI
    MC_SI=MC_SI+TI*WGT
    SWGT=SWGT+WGT
    SCHI=SCHI+TI2*WGT
    AVGI=MC_SI/SWGT
    CHI2A=(SCHI-MC_SI*AVGI)/(IT-0.9999d0)
    SD=DSQRT(ONE/SWGT)
    IF(NPRN.GE.0) THEN
      TSI=DSQRT(TSI)
      WRITE(NDEV,201) IT,TI,TSI,AVGI,SD,CHI2A
      ENDIF
    IF(NPRN.GT.0) THEN
      DO J=1,NDIM
         WRITE(NDEV,202) J,(XI(I,J),DI(I,J),I=1+NPRN/2,ND,NPRN)
      ENDDO
      ENDIF
!*************************************************************************************
!   REFINE GRID
!   XI(k,j)=XI(k,j)-(XI(k,j)-XI(k-1,j))*(sum(R(i),i=1,k)-s*sum(R(i),i=1,ND)/M)/R(k)
!   divides the original k-th interval into s parts
!*************************************************************************************
    outer2:DO J=1,NDIM
          XO=D(1,J)
          XN=D(2,J)
          D(1,J)=(XO+XN)/2.d0
          DT(J)=D(1,J)
          inner2:DO I=2,NDM
              D(I,J)=XO+XN
              XO=XN
              XN=D(I+1,J)
              D(I,J)=(D(I,J)+XN)/3.d0
              DT(J)=DT(J)+D(I,J)
          ENDDO inner2
          D(ND,J)=(XN+XO)/2.d0
          DT(J)=DT(J)+D(ND,J)
    ENDDO outer2

    le1:DO J=1,NDIM
        RC=0.d0
        DO I=1,ND
           R(I)=0.d0
           IF(D(I,J).GT.0.) THEN
               XO=DT(J)/D(I,J)
               R(I)=((XO-ONE)/XO/DLOG(XO))**ALPH
       ENDIF
           RC=RC+R(I)
        ENDDO
        RC=RC/XND
        K=0
        XN=0.d0
        DR=XN
        I=K
        LABEL=0
        le2:DO
        le3:DO
        IF(LABEL.EQ.0)THEN
                K=K+1
                DR=DR+R(K)
                XO=XN
                XN=XI(K,J)
        ENDIF
        IF(RC.LE.DR) THEN
                EXIT
        ELSE
                LABEL=0
        ENDIF
           ENDDO le3
           I=I+1
           DR=DR-RC
           XIN(I)=XN-(XN-XO)*DR/R(K)
           IF(I.GE.NDM) THEN
                   EXIT
           ELSE
                   LABEL=1
           ENDIF 
           ENDDO le2
        DO I=1,NDM
           XI(I,J)=XIN(I)
        ENDDO
        XI(ND,J)=ONE
    ENDDO le1

    IF(IT.GE.ITMX.OR.ACC*ABS(AVGI).GE.SD) EXIT
ENDDO mainloop
200   FORMAT(/," INPUT PARAMETERS FOR MC_VEGAS: ",/," NDIM=",I3,"    NCALL=",F8.0,&
     "     IT=",I3,/," ITMX=",I3,"    ACC=   ",G9.3,&
     "   NPRN=",I3,/," ALPH=",F5.2,"    MDS=",I3,"          ND=",I4,/,&
     "(XL,XU)=",(T10,"(" G12.6,",",G12.6 ")"))
201   FORMAT(/," INTEGRATION BY MC_VEGAS ", " ITERATION NO. ",I3, /,&
     " INTEGRAL = ",G14.8, /," SQURE DEV  = ",G10.4,/,&
     " ACCUMULATED RESULTS:   INTEGRAL = ",G14.8,/,&
     " DEV  = ",G10.4, /," CHI**2 PER IT'N = ",G10.4)
! X is the division of the coordinate
! DELTA I is the sum of F in this interval 
202   FORMAT(/,"DATA FOR AXIS ",I2,/,"    X       DELTA I       ", &
     24H   X       DELTA I      ,18H   X       DELTA I, &
      /(1H ,F7.6,1X,G11.4,5X,F7.6,1X,G11.4,5X,F7.6,1X,G11.4))
END SUBROUTINE VEGAS
END MODULE MC_VEGAS
```

`Main.f90`

```
program main
   use my_fxn
   use MC_VEGAS 
   implicit none

   integer, parameter        :: NDIM = 6
   real(kind(0d0))           :: avgi, sd, chi2a
   Character(len=40)         :: Tablefile
   data Tablefile/'CT14LL.pds'/
   Call SetCT14(Tablefile)
   call vegas(NDIM,fxn_1,avgi,sd,chi2a)

   print *, avgi
end program main
```

---

After running `build.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf *.mod
rm -rf *.o
rm -rf ./calc
rm DATAqq.txt

gfortran -c CT14Pdf.for
gfortran -c FXNqq.f90
gfortran -c MC_VEGAS.f90
gfortran -c MAINqq.f90

gfortran  -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall -o calc MAINqq.o CT14Pdf.o FXNqq.o MC_VEGAS.o
./calc
rm -rf *.mod
rm -rf *.o
rm -rf ./calc
```

The whole output has not changed

```
 rm: cannot remove 'DATAqq.txt': No such file or directory

 INPUT PARAMETERS FOR MC_VEGAS: 
 NDIM=  6    NCALL=  46875.     IT=  0
 ITMX=  5    ACC=   -1.00       NPRN=  5
 ALPH= 1.50    MDS=  1          ND=  50
(XL,XU)= ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )
         ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )
         ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )
         ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )
         ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )
         ( 0.00000    , 1.00000    )

 INTEGRATION BY MC_VEGAS  ITERATION NO.   1
 INTEGRAL =            NaN
 SQURE DEV  =        NaN
 ACCUMULATED RESULTS:   INTEGRAL =            NaN
 DEV  =        NaN
 CHI**2 PER IT'N =        NaN

DATA FOR AXIS  1
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000  0.2431E-14     .160000  0.5475E-15     .260000  0.8216E-14
 .360000  0.3641E-14     .460000  0.6229E-12     .560000  0.6692E-13
 .660000  0.9681E-15     .760000  0.9121E-15     .860000  0.2753E-13
 .960000 -0.9269E-16

DATA FOR AXIS  2
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000  0.1658E-13     .160000  0.5011E-14     .260000  0.8006E-12
 .360000  0.1135E-14     .460000  0.9218E-13     .560000  0.7337E-15
 .660000  0.6192E-12     .760000  0.3676E-14     .860000  0.2315E-14
 .960000  0.5426E-13

DATA FOR AXIS  3
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000  0.3197E-14     .160000  0.1096E-12     .260000  0.5996E-14
 .360000  0.5695E-13     .460000  0.3240E-14     .560000  0.5504E-13
 .660000  0.9276E-15     .760000  0.6193E-12     .860000  0.1151E-13
 .960000  0.7968E-17

DATA FOR AXIS  4
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000  0.3605E-13     .160000  0.1656E-14     .260000  0.7266E-12
 .360000  0.2149E-13     .460000  0.8086E-13     .560000  0.9119E-14
 .660000  0.3692E-15     .760000  0.6499E-15     .860000  0.1906E-17
 .960000  0.1542E-19

DATA FOR AXIS  5
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000 -0.4229E-15     .160000 -0.4056E-14     .260000 -0.1121E-14
 .360000  0.6757E-15     .460000  0.7460E-14     .560000  0.9331E-15
 .660000  0.8301E-14     .760000  0.6595E-14     .860000 -0.5203E-11
 .960000  0.6361E-12

DATA FOR AXIS  6
    X       DELTA I          X       DELTA I         X       DELTA I
 .060000  0.2111E-12     .160000  0.5410E-13     .260000  0.1418E-12
 .360000  0.1103E-13     .460000  0.8338E-14     .560000 -0.5840E-14
 .660000  0.1263E-14     .760000 -0.1501E-15     .860000  0.4647E-14
 .960000  0.3134E-15

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F9D828B0E08
#1  0x7F9D828AFF90
#2  0x7F9D81FE24AF
#3  0x43586C in __mc_vegas_MOD_vegas
#4  0x400EAE in MAIN__ at MAINqq.f90:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: *I have thought it hard* And have you noticed the error message speaks about module `vegas` and procedure `mc_vegas` in that module? Please show the relevant code. Does `mc_vegas` call the code you show? Which part of it? But even before that please compile the code with `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` and try to run it. Report what happened. Always use the compiler's error checking when debugging, it saves *a lot* of time.

Comment: Yes, it IS very likely abou an out of bounds error, even if you claim otherwise. Olease tell us why you think so.

Comment: @VladimirF , `MC_VEGAS` call `fxn_1`

Comment: I think so because the 2 results corresponding to `M_D=2.9d0` and `M_D=3.1` are close to each other.

Comment: Please try to recompile with the option above and try to run it and report the output. It may help a lot.

Comment: The problem may lie in inconsistent interfaces. Do *not* use `external` in modern Fortran. Although it seems to be actually applied consistently here, just hard to check.

Comment: Please compile the whole program wiht that option, not just one file. All files, link them and run the program. Do it like you normally do it and just add that option to all compilation commands.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you .

Comment: You still applied the option wrong. It must be included into ALL of your gfortran commands for all .for and .f90 files. It is really important to learn this, it will help you many times in the future.

Comment: @VladimirF you are right, I think finally it tell me something `At line 313 of file MC_VEGAS.f90 Fortran runtime error: Index '51' of dimension 1 of array 'r' above upper bound of 50`

Comment: @VladimirF Do you have any idea what should I do now?

Comment: You have to find out why `K` gets too large on line 313 (`DR=DR+R(K)`).